# How to implement php facebook sdk into cakephp?

Tags: facebook, cakephp

All the guides online are self-labeled out of date, and the most popular plugin I assume is Nick Baker's which currently isn't working.

So is there anything recent? Haven't found anything that really explains this after hours of searching google and tinkering with this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You could always chuck the facebook API in /vendors and use it yourself:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

or checkout the latest master of Nick's github:

https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin